# Why does JasperReports try to load org.springframework.core.io.Resource class?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, noclassdeffounderror

Recently we integrated JasperReports to our enterprise application. Some of our users get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource` at client side which is a Swing application. The `jnlp` file contains `jasperreports.jar` and no import of this class occurs in our code. Why does JasperReports try to load this class ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recreate the error on my pc and relaize that `jasperreports-chart-themes.jar` uses `spring-core.jar` and `jasperreports-functions.jar` uses jodatime api. so remove these jar if you really do not need otherwise add the depended jars.

Comment: Just for notice, the jasperreports-chart-themes.jar is not something that is distributed with jasper report see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.2.0,  and yes it contains a jasperreport_extension.properties calling spring functions since it has a Spring-based chart theme implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The `spring-core.jar` is an optional [jasper report dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.2.0)

Why is it trying to load it?,

I would check the jrxml files and the `jasperreports_extension.properties`.

Comment: i checked both file and find no clue.

Comment: Its most certainly inside a jasperreports_extension.properties, note they are also deployed inside the different jasper_report.jar's (root level). You need to recreate the error on a pc, then search the  jasperreports_extension.properties (different jar's in class path), to find who is instancing the class (or just add the spring-core.jar in your distribution ; )

Comment: yes i did exactly same thing, i recreate the error. and then added spring-core.jar but it did not enough for solving the class requirements. three more  depended jars i added for make report run. it is not a good solution for me to add all depended jars. so i decided to reduce the jar counts.  i removed jasperreports charts, themes, fonts jar from classpath and the problem is gone somehow. i still dont know the root cause of error. thanks for your helps.

Comment: @mfidan Probably the fonts jar, check the jasperreports_extension.properties inside of it.

Comment: @Peter Friberg not in fonts jar but in chart themes  jasperreports_extension.properties  contains this definition .net.sf.jasperreports.extension.chart.theme.spring.beans.resource=net/sf/jasperreports/chartthemes/spring/beans/chartThemesBeans.xml.

Comment: Removing it solved the issue?... I distinctly remembered a font issue since the spring framework included a font... think its the Helvetica font or something like that... thats why I suggest the font library...

Comment: i recrate the error and i removed the jars one by one. chart jar needs spring-core and functions jar needs joda-time.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with jasperreports-fonts-3.7.1

I'm using this jar with jasperreports-3.7.1 to display UTF8 character (using DejaVu Sans font)

The spring dependency is used in jasperreports_extension.properties of jasperreports-fonts-

I added the spring-core and spring-beans 2.5 to the classpath and the problem is solved